# Make /usr/lib/sendmail deliver local mail locally (submit.cf vs sendmail.cf)

Tags: sendmail

After changing my sendmail setup, I've got most things working, but 
sendmail incorrectly sends email to "foo@localhost" to port 25, 
instead of delivering it locally. How to fix?:

- Everything worked fine before the change, but I suspect 
  sendmail.cf was doing the work that submit.cf does no.
- When I email "foo@localhost", I want /usr/lib/sendmail to look in 
  /etc/mail/aliases (or aliases.db), and do a local delivery to foo's 
  target, which could be a local user, a pipe, a mailing list, etc.
- I do NOT want /usr/lib/sendmail to pass foo@localhost emails to 
  port 25. My port 25 is an stunnel: once an email reaches port 25, 
  there's no hope of local delivery.
- My /etc/hosts has "127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost", so 
  I think sendmail parses "localhost" as "localhost.localdomain", but 
  not sure.
- Here are the localhost-related entries in sendmail.cf 
  (tabs compressed to single space for viewing purposes)

http://pastebin.com/Tam8sz0F

[if someone could cut/paste the content of this + the other URLs into 
this message, I'd be most appreciative; my attempts failed miserably]

- And the localhost-related entries in submit.cf (also 
  tab-compressed)

http://pastebin.com/SSgCE6z3

- The diff between the two (diff submit.cf-chunk sendmail.cf-chunk):

http://pastebin.com/zReBBhhZ

- Yes, I realize the duplicate "Cw" entry in both files is 
  pointless, but it's never hurt sendmail.cf, so I'm not worried about 
  it yet.
- I'm tempted to tweak submit.cf's quoted lines to match 
  sendmail.cf's quoted lines, but I'd really like to 
  understand what's going on before doing anything more. The 
  hit-and-miss approach to *.cf editing is starting to worry me.

Answer (score 0):

You can start sendmail with the -Am switch and not use submit.cf at all. Or you can have a sendmail daemon listen in some other port and then tweak submit.cf to deliver there instead of port 25.